# Sample data for Developer Org

Tags: data

as I ran out of space, i've deleted the sample data (accounts and opportunities) from my developer org. 
Nom I'm trying to go though the trailhead modules, I realize I need the original data provided to complete some challenge. 
Does anyone got a backup of those sample data so that I can re-upload those in my DE? Or should I contact Salesforce for that?

Comment: Did you check the recycle bin and undelete those records? You should be able to do this assuming you didn't delete the data over 15 days ago and the amount of records in the sample data provided to Dev orgs is pretty small.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually have multiple developer orgs, it might be easier to just create a new developer org for trailhead and use the current org to play around with other items. Your username does not need to be a valid email address just in the form of an email address so you can create as many dev orgs as needed to learn.